# Alterar coluna para indentity utilizando T-SQL no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Preciso alterar uma coluna existente em uma tabela para que ela fique com a propriedade `identity` utilizando T-SQL e então inserir dados nesta tabela. A coluna já contem dados e após esta inserção, devo novamente alterar esta coluna desabilitando a propriedade `identity`. Atualmente preciso inserir os dados manualmente, vendo qual o ultimo número inteiro (index) para completar a inserção. Como fazer isso corretamente?

Comment: Não entendi você que colocar o id um a um ou que ele seja gerado automaticamente?

Comment: quero que seja gerado automaticamente um por um desde o ultimo acrescentado, e também no final do código volte a não gerar automaticamente.

Comment: Se é o que estou entendendo veja [isso aqui](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb734402(v=sql.110).aspx)`SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . ] table { ON | OFF }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acho que a sua pergunta ainda está um pouco confusa, você não está apresentando o seu problema real e partindo de uma solução que pode ser inadequada. Se o campo está marcado com `IDENTITY` é porque ele deve possuir alguma importância de integridade ou referencial para alguma relação externa.

Contudo, se você deseja realizar um `INSERT` definindo manualmente esse valor seja incrementando manualmente ou preenchendo gaps que podem ter ficado depois que alguns registros foram excluídos você deve usar a seguinte instrução:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SUA_TABELA] ON;
GO

INSERT INTO [SUA_TABELA] (ID, Campo, ...) VALUES (4, 'Valor', ...)
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SUA_TABELA] OFF; 
GO
```

Referência: [SET IDENTITY_INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188059(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: só para complementa `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SUA_TABELA] OFF;
GO` ; no final

Comment: Editado, thanks @MarconcilioSouza

Answer (score 4):

Se você que inserir um id automaticamente e depois voltar a inserir um a um você tem que usar `SET IDENTITY INSERT (SQL Server Compact)`.

Ele permite que valores explícitos sejam inseridos na coluna de identidade de uma tabela.
Sintaxe

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table { ON | OFF }
```

[Mais detalhes aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188059(v=sql.120).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Rodrigo, até onde sei, não tem como realizar essa alteração sem excluir e recriar a coluna. E para fazer isso via script e manter os dados já existentes acho que seria inviável.

Não seria mais fácil, quando o código não for enviado pelo usuário, você fazer uma função que te retorne o ID + 1 e gravar o registro normalmente?

Comment: Vou fazer desta forma mesmo assim vou continuar procurando, mas facilitaria muito ter alguma forma de fazer isso.
Obrigado